# Resource bundle expression for specific user group

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I have just created a new user group(customer), and resource bundle (customerBundle).

What I want is customerBundle, which includes some extra JS only for the new user group.

I have made this TTW for now and don't have a product to edit/add functionality to (this is next once I have it working as not 100% sure how to make an add-on yet using bob templates)

How can I do this? The solutions I have found so far, i get the 'insufficient privileges' error as using `plone.api`

Comment: I posted your question to our forum, at https://community.plone.org/t/stack-exchange-resource-bundle-expression-for-specific-user-group/4580 which is the best place to ask questions directly.

Comment: Can you point to the solutions you found so far? Couldn't find any info and as nobody's answering, I'm afraid it might not possible.